# Por que se diz “brócolos” em Portugal e “brócolis” no Brasil?

Tags: diferenças-transatlânticas

Segundo o Wikitionary, no Brasil diz-se *brócolis*, e em Portugal *brócolos*. E, em inglês, dizem *broccoli*, sem *-s*.

Por que dessa diferença?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Essa seria uma palavra relativamente recente no português, vinda do italiano — com o português de Portugal [se baseando](https://dicionario.priberam.org/br%C3%B3colos) no **singular** *broccolo*, e o do Brasil [se baseando](https://dicionario.priberam.org/br%C3%B3colis) no **plural** *broccoli*.

O Houaiss, via [Ciberdúvidas](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/brocolis-brocolos/29448), dá a seguinte etimologia:

> it[aliano] *broccolo* (pl[ural] it[aliano] *broccoli*), der[ivado] de *brocco* < lat[im] *broccus*, "que tem os dentes salientes, pontiagudos"; a ad[a]p[tação] para o port[uguês] é tardia (1871), com dois possíveis desdobramentos: de um lado, ad[a]p[tação] ao port[uguês] com a desin[ência] do pl[ural] it[aliano], donde as f[ormas] *brócoli/brócole*, que ganham no port[uguês] um pl[ural] no padrão vern[áculo] *brócolis/brocoles*; de outro, a própria f[orma] it[aliana] sing[ular], grafada *brócolo* no port[uguês], com pl[ural] t[am]b[ém] no padrão vern[áculo] *brócolos*; a var[iante] *brocos*, tida como vulg[ar], é prov[avelmente] f[orma] sinc[opada] pop[ular] de *brócolo/brócolos* (sem relação com o it[aliano] *brocco*, "graveto, pua", ou com a derivação desse voc[ábulo] no italiano);

Em que se nota haver em pt-PT uma terceira forma da palavra: [*brocos*](https://dicionario.priberam.org/brocos).

Comment: Essa terceira forma já a conhecia, mas só de dicionários. Ninguém a quem a apresentei a tinha ouvido ainda, e a mim soa-me "matarruana".

Comment: @ANeves Interessante.